# How to convert date yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, dateformatter

I am convert date from **"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"** to **"dd-mm-yyyy"** and my date is **"2018-09-11T09:53:25.000+0000"** and this is my code

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

let dateFromInputString = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-09-11T09:53:25.000+0000")

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"

if(dateFromInputString != nil){
   return dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromInputString!)
}
else{
   debugPrint("could not convert date")
   return "N/A"
}
```

but i am getting converted date **11-23-2018** like this

But my aspect is **11-09-2018**

Comment: You live in India, right? Where the timeZone is 5:30 different no? You get "23", because it's "53-30 minutes". Why? Because you used `mm` for the month instead of `MM` (twice by the way, in the first format and in the second one).

Comment: Side note and not related, but use `if let` instead of `!= nil` followed with a force unwrap: `if let date = dateFromInputString { return dateFormatter.string(from: date)}`

Comment: @Larme thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

 let dateFromInputString = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-09-11T09:53:25.000+0000")

 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

 if(dateFromInputString != nil){
     return dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromInputString!)
 }
 else{
     debugPrint("could not convert date")
     return "N/A"
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `dateFormat` is **wrong**. The ambiguity in your format should have been clear when you used 'mm' for *both* months and minutes.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

mm - minutes

MM - months

The same goes for the second date format too.

---

Refer [this](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more information on date formats.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
 func GetFormatedDate(date_string:String,dateFormat:String)-> String{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat

    let dateFromInputString = dateFormatter.date(from: date_string)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // Here you can use any dateformate for output date
    if(dateFromInputString != nil){
        return dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromInputString!)
    }
    else{
        debugPrint("could not convert date")
        return "N/A"
    }
}
```

**Use Like this :**

```
self.GetFormatedDate(date_string: "2018-09-11T09:53:25.000+0000", dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

**Output :**

```
11-09-2018
```

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

Try it

Answer (score 1):

Your dateFormater is wrong it should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` not this `yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

`dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"`

to

`dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   extension String {

        func convertDate() -> String {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

            if let dateInLocal = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
                return dateFormatter.string(from: dateInLocal)
            }
            return "NA"
        }

    }
```